# Help! Transaction unconfirmed after 1 day!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a bitcoin transfer yesterday and it is still pending with 0 confirmation. The fee is around 0.003BTC and the miner preference is high though. Can anyone please help me get it confirmed? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the link:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/b79bffaec87a0e789be3465faecc394f692ef2c501ef2787dcbc3f56e16c7076/

Answer (score -1):

At this point, AFAIK, no one can help you speed things up. There has been a record number of transactions over the last few days and the queue is really backed up.